# AS3/Flash/Air: Database sharing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an AIR application that stores data in XML files. The databases is located in the **documentsDirectory** folder of a main computer.

Is it possible to update the data of the XML files from other computers of a network?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

hypothetically:

- We have a server
- We have a shared folder with read/write access.
- In the folder we have the database files (XML)

Is it possible to update the database file from any computer with access to the shared folder?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible without using a server ...

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the file, but it won't work if multiple application tries to write  the file at the same time.
And, lets say app A changes one data, and app B changes another data. App A writes the new XML, then B writes its own version of the XML without acknowledging the changes from A. The changes from A are lost.

One way to go here is SQLite. Natively supported in AIR. But then again, you can not write the file at the same time from 2 different apps. AIR is supposed to handle those writing issues, but i already experienced some problems with it.

A much better way to go here would be setting a SQL server up (or any other real DB server, i am no expert) and some php interface. Maybe AMFPHP : http://gotoandlearn.com/search.php?q=amf, or simply use urlloaders ...

Comment: djib: The app has a step by step usage. The user fills a form whit his data in the first screen. The XML is only writed when the user reaches the last screen (there are 10 screens). What I have done is to refresh (reload) the XML every time a user reaches that screen. Then his data is added to the XML. 

I think that way will be very difficult simultaneous changes.

The application is used no more than 500 times a year, but can be used simultanusly by several users.

Is it a good practice?

Comment: There exists an Admin application also, but it's is only used by one person.